# Laravel pivot table generate did not work (return General error: 1005 Can't create table)

Tags: laravel

I am trying to crate pivot table for store extra items in a hotel. To do that,

**First I crated hotels table,**

```
    Schema::create('hotels', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('photo');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->comment('1 - enable, 0 - disable');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Then I created extra_items table,**

```
    Schema::create('extra_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Also I created currencies table,**

```
    Schema::create('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->tinyInteger('default')->default(0)->comment('0 - not default, 1 - default');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Finally, I tried to create pivot table, but when I tried to migrate, it threw following error,**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1005 Can't create table `hotels`.`#sql-3038_ab` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
>   `extra_item_hotel` add constraint
>   `extra_item_hotel_extra_item_id_foreign` foreign key (`extra_item_id`)
>   references `extra_items` (`id`))

This is how I created the migration file,

```
    Schema::create('extra_item_hotel', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('extra_item_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('hotel_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('currency_id');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1)->comment('0 - disable, 1 - enable');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('hotel_id')->references('id')->on('hotels');
        $table->foreign('extra_item_id')->references('id')->on('extra_items');
        $table->foreign('currency_id')->references('id')->on('currencies');

    });
```

**Actually I can not find the reason for the error, for your reference, I created similar type pivot tables without any issues in this project, for example,**

```
    Schema::create('hotel_meal_plan', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('hotel_id');
        $table->foreign('hotel_id')->references('id')->on('hotels');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('meal_plan_id');
        $table->foreign('meal_plan_id')->references('id')->on('meal_plans');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('currency_id');
        $table->foreign('currency_id')->references('id')->on('currencies');
        $table->float('amount');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Could someone please help me to find the issue, Thank you.

Comment: try changing to `unsignedBigInteger` in the line `$table->unsignedInteger('hotel_id');` when you create `extra_item_hotel` table

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key column and the referencing column should be same type.

[HERE](https://laraveldaily.com/be-careful-laravel-5-8-added-bigincrements-as-defaults/) is good article that explains similar situation to yours.